# Failed migration?

Tags: support, specific-question, migration

What happened to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/159294/random-operators)? When I saw it in the review queue, it had 3 votes to migrate to MSE, and 1 vote to close (Yemon's custom reason). But after I cast the last vote to close, it is now put on hold instead of being migrated. Is there an obvious reason why the migration failed?

(For the record, I voted to close because there is already a [duplicate on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696388/random-operators) and it felt like it made sense to merge the two versions together at the site where it appears more suitable, given the current phrasing.)

Comment: The question has now been migrated to [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/700554/random-operators).

Comment: I think you gave the reason yourself. The question would be a dupe on target site and this is reason for automatic rejection (I am pretty sure I read that recently on meta.SO but cannot find it ATM if I find a source I will upgrade tp an answer).

Comment: @quid No, only the other closure reasons make the migration be rejected. Closing as a duplicate is an exception (unless they changed this).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft we are talking about different types of mig rej. You're right for usual (user caused) rejections. But I talk about *automatic* rej, ie, one done without any user action on target site, even somehow before the question arrived on target site. Checking the questions edit hist you can see this was instant, the q never arrived on math.SE to be closed there. This auto rej happens AFAIK (at least) for no matching tag, OP (question) banned on target, and duplicate detected by software. I might misremember but I mentioned this slightly before in chat in a different context.

Comment: @quid Ahh, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais: thanks. Did the question show up in the failed migration logs that mods have access to? If so, does it give a reason?

Comment: @quid: where did you see that? The [MSO faq on migration](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) only mentions Q-bans and tag problems.

Comment: I don't recall where I saw it, else I could find the source. And, I also checked the FAQ you linked and noted it is not there. Still I am pretty sure I saw it. While I could imagine my memory playing tricks on me here as you set the context it is more difficult for me to imagine I dreamt up what I wrote in chat before http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14058678#14058678  As I say I might misrember of have misunderstood it. Sorry that I cannot say more than: I am pretty sure I read it but I cannot find it now.

Comment: I'm looking into this because it doesn't appear to be due to tags, or the user's ability to ask questions. What remains is that another _identical_ version of the question was on Math prior to this being migrated, but I'm not aware of any duplicate content checks.

Comment: OT to answer a question on a now deleted question:  I do not know exactly when/why migrations meta->main became imposisble but it seems like a global recent change. The issue is that not rarely questions asked by mistake on meta are such that they might be closed on main too (at least initially). Then, one has a rejected migration and the ensuing mess (question being locked on main where it should be improved...). The idea was for example mentioned on meta.math by a user known by many names, on a feature-request by Asaf. Possibly, they pushed through the change, which I find an improvement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I updated the meta post. Another *byte by byte* copy of that question existed on Math SE prior to the migration, which is why it was automatically rejected by the system.

We *do* appear to log this, I'm going to investigate getting the reason for the automatic rejection to be visible in the question's timeline that is visible to moderators.

I'm not certain *when* we started duplicate content checking on migration events, but I don't think it was recent - just rare enough that it's not easily noticed.

Comment: It would be continuously creepy if there isn't a first time that this happened, but it never happened before 2014. Also quantum creepy.

Comment: Some people on MathOverflow and Math.StackExchange want to prevent multiple identical posts on those two sites, and discourage simultaneous cross-posting. As described by Willie Wong in the question, that was partly the motivation for this failed migration. In fact, I also voted to migrate the question for the same reason. The check for duplicate content which you describe specifically prevented the intended migration. Do you have any comments or suggestions?

Comment: I believe there was another case of a failed migration due to there already being a duplicate at the target site: the question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/162427/accelerating-em-algorithm is a duplicate of http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92281/… (even though the titles are different) and appears to have failed to migrate to stats.stackexchange.com upon its closure.